# Ad with id `0` is not available for onAdFailedToLoad

Tags: android, flutter, admob, ads

I am trying to load a test As but I don't have any error in the code, but I am getting the following...

I/Ads     (30634): Ad failed to load : 0
I/flutter (30634): Ad with id `0` is not available for onAdFailedToLoad.

I am watching this YouTube video [Flutter AdMob](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IqOB6xCcPgU), And I am currently implementing the banner ads, now I rechecked the code many times, but couldn't understand what's wrong.

## AdMob Service...

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:google_mobile_ads/google_mobile_ads.dart';

class AdMobService {
  static String? get bannerAdUnitId {
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      return 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111';
    }
    return null;
  }

  static String? get interstitialAdUnitId {
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      return 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712';
    }
    return null;
  }

  static final BannerAdListener bannerListener = BannerAdListener(
    onAdLoaded: (ad) => debugPrint('Ad Loaded'),
    onAdFailedToLoad: (ad, error) {
      ad.dispose();
      debugPrint('Ad failed to load $error');
    },
    onAdOpened: (ad) => debugPrint('Ad opened'),
    onAdClosed: (ad) => debugPrint('Ad closed'),
  );
}
```

## main.dart

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  MobileAds.instance.initialize();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
}
```

## SearchScreen (where I am implementing the ads)

```
class SearchScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SearchScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SearchScreen> createState() => _SearchScreenState();
}

class _SearchScreenState extends State<SearchScreen> {
  final TextEditingController searchController = TextEditingController();
  bool isShowUsers = false;
  BannerAd? _banner;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _createBannerAd();
  }

  void _createBannerAd() {
    _banner = BannerAd(
      size: AdSize.fullBanner,
      adUnitId: AdMobService.bannerAdUnitId!,
      listener: AdMobService.bannerListener,
      request: const AdRequest(),
    )..load();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    **  bottomNavigationBar: _banner == null
          ? Container()
          : Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 12),
        height: 52,
        child: AdWidget(ad: _banner!),
      ),**
      drawer: const DrawerWidget(),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12, vertical: 40),
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: lightBlueColor,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
              ),
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 18, vertical: 4),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  const Image(
                    image: AssetImage('icons/search.png'),
                    width: 18,
                    color: kPrimaryColor,
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(width: 20),
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      controller: searchController,
                      style: const TextStyle(
                          color: kPrimaryColor, fontFamily: 'Sen'),
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'Search',
                        hintStyle:
                        TextStyle(color: Colors.black45, fontFamily: 'Sen'),
                        border: InputBorder.none,
                      ),
                      onSubmitted: (String value) {
                        setState(() {
                          isShowUsers = true;
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

## Android Manifest

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3419835294" />
```

It would be great if you could help me in it, I almost tried everything, I know I must be making some mistake but couldn't find. And also I currently just working on Android so that's the reason I haven't written or mention IOS in the AdMob Service.

Comment: One of the reasons could be an unstable internet connection.

Comment: At first, I thought the same, and then check in a few other devices as well, but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Use this Line

```
size: AdSize.banner
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: Appreciate your help, but unfortunately, it's not solving the problem. Also, I saw I have a admit so do you think this error is because of that, Although it's a test ad?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think one of the reasons could be the ad limit on the AdMob account. You should check if you have an ad limit

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the internet connection, you have to check it